# Travis CI build status failed. What can I do?

Tags: github, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I am new in project continuous deployment. I only add my [project](https://github.com/al2helal/HandicraftStore) in Travis CI and add the status logo in my github repo README.md. My project is created using php,html,javascript,bootstrap. And, my project is also connected with mysql database.

Now, what can I do so that it results successful build status.

**Edit 1**
As I new I don't know where the error message stored by travis ci. But, I can see a job log.

Comment: There's not enough in this question for anybody to help.  What errors are you getting (the exact errors from Travis CI, included directly in the question as text)?

Comment: @StephenNewell As I new I don't know where the error message stored by travis ci. But, I can see a job log. Should I include this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The job log is where you can find out what went wrong. Simply read the logs generated by travis, i.e. here: https://travis-ci.org/al2helal/HandicraftStore/builds/373415975

The error message you're getting is:

```
The command "phpunit" exited with 2.
```

Since you haven't defined what you want Travis to do in your `.travis.yml`, but only configured the language (php), Travis runs the default set of tests for the configured language. In your case it runs phpunit.

However, you haven't written any tests nor you have configured phpunit, so it only displays a help message and exits with an error code.

Before you deploy your automatically anywhere you should run tests that confirm your application is working as expected. Start with writing some.

Next, you'll need to configure Travis to run those tests and configure deployment if all tests pass.

Since you don't seem to know anything about Travis CI, the best place to start is just go through their docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/